# How can I combine Relative and Linear to achieve this XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I would like to create the

`Layout` that comes out in the attached image but I am not able, or it moves or I overlap and I do not fit perfect playing with width and height. I would like to have a horizontal `listview`, which I will put inside a `LinerLayout` which is what is in red and the 4 rectangles in orange (which I have tried to be `Relative` will be buttons or `imagebutton` that I will put inside, but I have not been able to do it.

I have tried to put `FrameLayout` and inside it I can already play a little more with the `Relative` but I always place myself in the upper left corner and there is no way to move them to the right or down and I would like everything to be square. Someone who has done something similar or similar?

[image]

My code but I can't achieve my image with orange and red rectangles.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:stretchColumns="1">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="173dp">

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: My code is useless because as you can read that this xml is impossible for me , so I could only put 1 ``linearlayout`` and 1 ``framelayout`` with ``RelativeLaoyut``, but dont worry, now I update my question with my code.....

Comment: @Rasi I have update my code, please, help me with my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

in res/drawable/border.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You have put 1 background with ``stroke`` but If I want 1 different colour in background in all 4 imagebutton, Can I put 4 ``borders.xml`` with different background colour?

Comment: yes you can...you have to change the stroke color and apply different background drawable for each imagebuttons

Comment: One question, if I want 1 textview on top of listview, only can I put textView on top and all ok?, but I can't do this.. T.T

Comment: sure you can add textview on top just change the first Linearlayout orientation to vertical `android:orientation="vertical"`...and add the textview

Comment: okay, perfect! thanks for all, you are simply the best haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Make relative layout the parent.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation=horizontal"
    android:alignParentTop=""
    android:id="llTopH".....>
       <your code for top layout>
  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation=horizontal"
    android:layout_below="llTopH"
    android:weightSum = "2"
    android:id="llTopH2".....>

     <LineraLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:weight = "1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

  <LineraLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:weight = "1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

this will two layouts on 2nd line

 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation=horizontal"
    android:layout_below="llTopH2"
    android:weightSum = "2"
    android:id="llTopH3".....>

      <LineraLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:weight = "1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

      <LineraLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:weight = "1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

this will two layouts on 3rd line

 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="4"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"

          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

      <ImageButton
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
<
```